# Symfony based autocomplete breaks SCP autocomplete

Tags: bash, symfony, autocomplete

I am using the PHP tools http://robo.li and n98-magerun.phar - both are based on Sympfony's CLI components.

When I use such a autocomplete script:

```
https://gist.github.com/caseyfw/51bdbcb37e5dfb91b74e

#!/bin/sh
function __robo_list_cmds ()
{
      robo list --raw | awk '{print $1}' | sort
}

function __robo_list_opts ()
{
    robo list --no-ansi | sed -e '1,/Options:/d' -e '/^$/,$d' -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/ .*//' | sort
}

_robo()
{
    local cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$(__robo_list_opts) $(__robo_list_cmds)" -- ${cur}))
    return 0;
}

complete -o default -F _robo robo
COMP_WORDBREAKS=${COMP_WORDBREAKS//:}
```

It breaks the autocomplete of the `scp` command (which usually completes files on a remote server - but with this - unrelated - robo completion in place, scp  removes the host name from the command)

Why is that? How to fix?

**EDIT**

based on the answer, the fixed version is here:

https://gist.github.com/amenk/d68f1fe54b156952ced621f771ff48ba

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but side note: completion scripts are *sourced*, (typically in `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`), so the shebang line is inconsequential. If it were *not* ignored, things would break because `sh` doesn't know about arrays, but you use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has probably nothing to do with your `robo` compspec. Nor with the `_scp` completion function associated with `scp`.

It is probably due to your `COMP_WORDBREAKS=${COMP_WORDBREAKS//:}`.

You removed `:` from the list of separators. Apparently `_scp` is robust enough to behave the same with or without `:` as a word separator. It returns the same list of candidate completions. But the token that gets substituted when `_scp` returns only one candidate for the completion of, e.g. `scp host:public_ht`, is `host:public_ht`, instead of just `public_ht`. Proof:

```
$ _foobar () { COMPREPLY=bazcux; return 0; }
$ complete -o default -F _foobar foobar
$ echo $COMP_WORDBREAKS
"'><=;|&(:
```

If you try to complete `foobar host:public_ht`, you get `foobar host:bazcux` because the substituted token is just `public_ht`. While with:

```
$ COMP_WORDBREAKS=${COMP_WORDBREAKS//:}
$ echo $COMP_WORDBREAKS
"'><=;|&(
```

if you try to complete `foobar host:public_ht`, you get `foobar bazcux` because it is the complete `host:public_ht` that is replaced by `bazcux`.

The solution to your problem is probably to adapt your `_robo` completion function such that it does not require that `:` is not a word separator. Something like:

```
_stem () {
    local lcur lprev
    lcur="$cur"
    stem="$lcur"
    for (( i = cword - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1 )); do
        lprev="${words[i]}"
        [[ $lcur == ":" ]] && [[ $lprev == ":" ]] && break
        [[ $lcur != ":" ]] && [[ $lprev != ":" ]] && break
        stem="$lprev$stem"
        lcur="$lprev"
    done
}

_robo () {
    local cur prev words cword
    _init_completion || return
    local stem options
    options=($(__robo_list_opts) $(__robo_list_cmds))
    COMPREPLY=()
    _stem
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W '${options[@]}' -- "$stem"))
    [[ $stem =~ : ]] && stem=${stem%:*}: && COMPREPLY=(${COMPREPLY[@]#"$stem"})
    return 0
}

complete -o default -F _robo robo
```

A much (apparently) simpler solution consists in replacing the `_stem` function above by the existing `__reassemble_comp_words_by_ref` function of the `bash_completion` library:

```
_robo () {
    local cur prev words cword
    _init_completion || return
    __reassemble_comp_words_by_ref ":" words cword
    options=($(__robo_list_opts) $(__robo_list_cmds))
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W '${options[@]}' -- "$cur"))
    return 0
}

complete -o default -F _robo robo
```

All this is probably not exactly what you want. I do not know `robo.il` and there are probably many improvements that would take more context into account to propose specific completions. But it may be a starting point.

Comment: "The solution to your problem is probably to adapt your _robo completion function such that it does not require that : is not a word separator." how would that work? roughly? Where does it require those wordbreaks?

Comment: Ah, the thing is that robo/symfony commands are like this: `robo main:sub:subsubcommand`  so maybe this is why the wordseperator comes in to place. Is it possible to activate that word separator only for `robo` & `magerun`, not for `scp`?

Comment: @Alex No, I do  not think you can specialize `COMP_WORDBREAKS` per command, unfortunately. You will really have to implement a bit more complex `_robo` function to 1) parse the `COMP_WORDS` array backwards starting from `COMP_CWORD` to build the `main:sub:subsu` stem, 2) call `compgen` to get all possible completions, 3) remove the stem from them and return the result. Note that their are two possibilities: word-level completion (stopping at `:` like path completion stops at `/`) or full group completion. It is your choice.

Comment: You're welcome. I added a new version using existing `bash_completion` functions. The behaviour should be the same but it is probably better to rely on `bash_completion`.